# Text Animation and Background change

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm stuck and need help.

[image]

How can I add animations like on the picture. I want **the color of the background and text to be smoothly automatically changed** 1 sec after the app is launched. And to be like a cycle. Meanwhile an **icon is impulsing**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Property Animation for changing color

```
int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(500); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        textView.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

Use alpha animations to fade in and out the textchanging So on repeat is when it is fading back in so you can update the text at that time

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.setRepeatCount(1);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        txtLabel.startAnimation(anim);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                txtLabel.setText("my next Text"); //for fading back in
            }
        });
```

You can use the same animation for alpha on a bitmap or imageView to pulse in and out as well.

```
AlphaAnimation animPulse = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    animPulse.setDuration(500);
    animPulse.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animPulse.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    imgPulse.startAnimation(animPulse);
```

Then of course just put in your

```
public void onCreate(){
      Handler mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.prepareMainLooper());
      mMainHandler.postDelay(new Runnable(){
           doAnimations();
      }, 1000);
}
```

Then simply lump all your animations into methods and call them from doAnimations. Good luck.

Comment: Mixing Java and Kotlin in the same answer might be confusing for less experienced readers

Comment: lol, thanks jahnold. I didn't even realize i did that. I just copy and pasted the snippets from different projects and then manually typed the onCreate piece. So didn't realize I copied from two different languages. I fixed to only Java. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

I did the code to change color of background layout and text. Currently I did for random colors, if you need pre-defined colors, please let me know. Below is my code

1. activity_main.xml

`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.golevr.background_animation.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/constraint">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

2. MainActivity.java

`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            // Move your declarations here if you intend on using them after the onCreate() method
            ConstraintLayout layout;
            TextView textView;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                // Inflate your objects
                layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint);
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                // We change the color to RED for the first time as the program loads
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                // We change the color to GREEN for the first time as the program loads
                textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                // Create the timer object which will run the desired operation on a schedule or at a given time
                Timer timer = new Timer();

                // Create a task which the timer will execute.  This should be an implementation of the TimerTask interface.
                // I have created an inner class below which fits the bill.
                MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();

                // We schedule the timer task to run after 1000 ms and continue to run every 1000 ms.
                timer.schedule(myTimer,1000,1000);
            }

            // An inner class which is an implementation of the TImerTask interface to be used by the Timer.
            class MyTimer extends TimerTask{
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // This runs in a background thread.
                    // We cannot call the UI from this thread, so we must call the main UI thread and pass a runnable
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Random rand = new Random();

                            // The random generator creates values between [0,256) for use as RGB values used below to create a random color
                            // We call the RelativeLayout object and we change the color.  The first parameter in argb() is the alpha.
                            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rand.nextInt(256),rand.nextInt(256),rand.nextInt(256)));
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.argb(222,rand.nextInt(222),rand.nextInt(222),rand.nextInt(222)));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

`

Is this what you want?